# Lua API unload luaL_loadfile

Tags: api, lua

I working on Lua scripter in game that users are able to write custom Lua script and load it.

I already done with implementation and functions

```
L = luaL_newstate()
luaL_openlibs()
lua_register(L, cFunction, "luaFunction")
lua_register(L, cFunction2, "luaFunction2")
lua_register(L, cFunctionN, "luaFunctionN")
```

What I trying now?
Possibility to execute/kill script on button press, below picture for more clarity : https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJQzg.png

All scripts from scripter need to access to Lib.lua so i do:

```
luaL_loadfile(L, "Lib.lua")
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)
```

Then to load script i could use this same thing and is ok until user want to kill/unload script.

```
luaL_loadfile(L, "script.lua")
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)
```

I digging in many threads about Lua API and currently no good answer for this problem.

Ppls talking about lua_newthread that i already tried to implement but no success.

```
T = lua_newthread(L)
luaL_loadfile(L, "script.lua")
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)
Return >> Attempt to call a nill value. Look like new thread has no access to Lib.lua
```

Also there is other problem, when i register function i use:

```
lua_register(L, cFunction, "luaFunction")
```

Then even i able to create a thread functions from luaL_newstate*L required to pass handle L to working while handle of thread is T.

Example of C function passing to lua:

```
 static int add (lua_State *L) {
      double a = lua_tonumber(L, -1);  /* get argument 1 */
      double b = lua_tonumber(L, -2);  /* get argument 2 */ 
      lua_pushnumber(L, a+b);  /* push result */
      return 1;  /* number of results */
    }
```

Any king of is appreciated.

Regards,
Ascer

Comment: nvm solved it out :) I created a single luaL_state for each script and register all functions then create an array for keep all registry. To close just use lua_close(scriptHandle)